# SQL Arithmetic Overflow error converting varchar to decimal when limiting values in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a CTE query that converts a varchar field into a decimal.
However, in the `SELECT` after the CTE I want to limit the values returned.
This is when I get the

> arthimetic overflow error

This is the query:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT PP.PatientProfileID, 
        ROUND(CAST( CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(O.Value) = 1 THEN O.Value END AS DECIMAL(4, 1)), 1) AS BmiValue
FROM PatientProfile PP RIGHT OUTER JOIN Encounter E1 ON PP.PatientProfileID = E1.PatientProfileID
        JOIN Procedures P on E1.PatientEncounterID = P.PatientEncounterID
        JOIN Observation O ON O.PatientProfileID = E1.PatientProfileID
WHERE P.CPTCode = '3008F' AND
    O.Term = 'BMI' AND O.Value IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE BmiValue >= 18.5 AND BmiValue < 25.0
```

When I limit the where clause to just: `WHERE BmiValue >= 18.5` there is no error.
When I only use `WHERE BmiValue < 25.0` there is no error.
Only when I use both expressions is there an arithmetic overflow error.

What is wrong with the query?

**UPDATE**
As I stated in my comments, I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.
I eliminate nulls in the CTE for the decimal values.  When I remove the `WHERE` clause, all of the values for `BmiValue` appear to be decimal values.

If I narrow the selection of `BmiValues` to this `WHERE` clause:
`WHERE (BmiValue >= 18.5) AND (BmiValue < 30.0)`
There is no arithmetic overflow error.
When I change the max value to this:
`WHERE (BmiValue >= 18.5) AND (BmiValue < 29.0)`
I get the arithmetic overflow error...weird.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: How does this work with two tables aliased as "P"?

Comment: @JacobH if the database is using a case sensitive collation those are in fact different aliases.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @SeanLange

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I updated the query.  It was a typo error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is an overflow error, you can try increasing the size of the `decimal()`. No guarantees there is not another issue with the `cast()` though.

```
;with CTE as (
  select PP.PatientProfileID
    , ROUND(CAST(case when ISNUMERIC(O.Value) = 1 then O.Value end as decimal(19, 6)), 1) as BmiValue
  from PatientProfile PP
  right join Encounter E1 on PP.PatientProfileID = E1.PatientProfileID
  inner join Procedures p on E1.PatientEncounterID = p.PatientEncounterID
  inner join Observation O on O.PatientProfileID = E1.PatientProfileID
  where p.CPTCode = '3008F' and O.Term = 'BMI' and O.Value is not null
 )
select *
from CTE
where BmiValue >= 18.5 and BmiValue < 25.0
```

---

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)
- [Why doesn’t `isnumeric()` work correctly? (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/)

Comment: Can't use this answer. I am on SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: Increasing the decimal cast fixed the problem!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to run math on a null value.

1) `ISNUMERIC()` returns true on more than just numbers (including '-', '+', '$', etc.).  Look into using `TRY_CAST()` instead.

2) Your CASE statement needs an ELSE clause.  Otherwise, you're attempting to `CAST` any `ISNUMERIC() = false` (i.e., null values) to a `DECIMAL`.

Beyond that, use `BETWEEN` in your where clause -- just cleaner.

Comment: `null` would not cause the overflow error, and the `between` advice seems like a bad idea to me. [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I eliminate `null` values in the `CTE`...`O.Value IS NOT NULL`